# jQuery plugin pattern via multiple instance and accessible method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, design-patterns, jquery-plugins

What is the best jQuery pattern for the following purposes?

- *Multiple instance* of plugin in one page or *common selector* to send

  > $(".class").myplugin();
- Custom accessible method to invoke from outside :

  > $("#ID").myplugin("command");

---

I read several articles and eventually got this pattern:


[**Sample on Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jj89198103/nbhgLazq/)

#### Making Instance

```
  $.fn.extend({
    myplugin: function(options) {
      if (!options || typeof(options) == 'object') {
        opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options);
      }

      this.each(function() {
        new $(this).myPlugin(options);
      });
      return;
    }
  });
```

---

#### Define accessible methods

```
  $.fn.myPlugin = function(methodOrOptions) {

    var method = {
      init: function() {

      },
      command: function() {

      }
    };

    if (method[methodOrOptions]) {
      return method[methodOrOptions].apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } 
    else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
      return method.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    else {
      $.error('method ' + methodOrOptions + 'not exist . . . :( . . .');
    }

  };
```

---

**Now, I want to know the real solution, is my pattern wrong?
I am looking for the best pattern...**

Comment: Look at the jQuery UI Widget Factory https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/.

Comment: Thanks, I have read this article, but it was not comprehensive enough about this question